# Is it possible to pick review questions with a minimum number of existing close votes?

Tags: support, review, voting, vote-to-close

I am reviewing and voting many questions to close and some to re-open.  Is it possible to get the review list with questions that are almost closed? Say instead of voting on a question with 1 close vote, I would like to vote on ones with 4 or 3. I could not find a way.

(I guess by doing this we could reduce number of questions that are pending decisions.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Presently, Close votes questions come randomly in the review queue.

But looking at your last sentence,

> I guess by doing this we could reduce number of questions that are pending decisions

IMHO it is not appropriate, because close votes review is not only for closing a question. It is also for leaving good questions open. So good questions having one or two close votes should also be reviewed with priority.

Comment: @ hims056: I understand that part. Even then, why should 'random' be better than some order, say close vote or creation time etc....